# Javascript: What is wrong with this conditional?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension an I've hit a wall.

```
function isInQueue(id) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({getQueueItems: 1}, function(response) {
        var items = response.items;
        if (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if ((items[i].id == id) == true) return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else { return false; }
    });
}
```

The request returns 'items' which is an array of objects. I am trying to see if another item *outside* of the queue already exists *inside* the queue. For example, there is an item on the outside with an id equal to '198677'. I know I already have an exact copy of that same item in my queue with the exact same id, '198677', however, when I test the two for equality `(items[i].id == id) == true`, it returns false. I have checked the typeof both and they are both strings. I have tried using `===` and that hasn't worked. I tried adding zero to each of them to turn them into integers and that made the function return true when it was actually true, however, when I tested for true `if (isInQueue(id) == true)` the conditional returned false.

This is all very confusing and frustrating for me. They're both strings, why doesn't it work?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
function isInQueue(id) {
    var result = false;
    var queue = localStorage["queue_rss"];
    if (queue != undefined) {
        var items = JSON.parse(queue).items;
        if (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if ((items[i].id == id) == true) {
                  result = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I should have done it that way in the first place.
Thanks guys. :D

Comment: @X Enterprises: you don't need to call a callback function with the result here, since you're not doing anything asynchronous. You can remove the callback parameter and just finish with `return result;` instead of `callback(result);`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `chrome.extension.sendRequest` is asynchronous - it returns immediately, but the callback function you provide to it will only be called once the request has completed.

The usual way to handle something like this is to pass a callback to your `isInQueue` method; the callback is called when the asynch operation is completed with the result.

```
function isInQueue(id, callback) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({getQueueItems: 1}, function(response) {
        var result = false;
        var items = response.items;
        if (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if ((items[i].id == id) == true) {
                  result = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually, `sendRequest` **returns immediately** without waiting for its callback function to execute rather than 'does not return immediately'. The not waiting for callback function to execute part is what's making it impossible for the callback function to return values.

Comment: @slebetman: You're absolutely correct. I'll correct my wording.

Comment: Just for clarification: even more, it is simply impossible that `chrome.extension.sendRequest` doesn't return immediately but `inInQueue` does, because JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: I do have the queue stored in localStorage as stringified JSON. I should probably just get the 'items' that way. Let me try that.

Comment: @X Enterprises: It's almost always better to use a cache if you can.